# Adding sequential codes to GPS waypoints

Tags: gps, garmin

When using a GPS (a Garmin GPSmap 62 -- but our team has other similar equipment), when I want to add a new waypoint, the system displays a default number for it (e.g. 202). If I add the 202, the next point will be 203 and so on.

But, since the points I want to add belong to a project, I want to add a different code, intrinsic to the project (like ABC123, from project ABC, number 123). So I want to add the point ABC123, and configure the GPS in a way that the next suggested number will be ABC124, not 202 again (which causes an awful waste of time, after some points).

Does anybody know if this configuration exists in my device or perhaps in a different, more advanced model?